# How to create instance of Twitter::Tweet to create retweeted_by_user

Tags: ruby, twitter

I want to call retweeted_by_user(user, options = {}). How do I create instance of object Twitter::Tweet (in Twitter::REST::Timelines module) to call this method. It is instance method, correct?

I did this for Twitter::REST::CLIENT

```
 client = client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key     = "..."
  config.consumer_secret  = "..."
  config.access_token     = "..."
  config.access_token_secret = "..."
end
```

but it does not work for Twitter::Tweet

```
 client = client = Twitter::Tweet.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key     = "..."
  config.consumer_secret  = "..."
  config.access_token     = "..."
  config.access_token_secret = "..."
end
```

Here are the docs for Twitter gem. I need a little more explanation
http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Timelines#retweeted_by_user-instance_method

Comment: Double posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727429/create-object-to-call-retweeted-by-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spec are the best documentation and explanation:

client:
https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/c9cfca9bf156ac0569d6c2cd7117327daf10a643/spec/twitter/rest/timelines_spec.rb#L6

method usage:
https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/c9cfca9bf156ac0569d6c2cd7117327daf10a643/spec/twitter/rest/timelines_spec.rb#L58