# create object to call retweeted_by_user

Tags: ruby, twitter

I am using the Ruby Twitter gem. I want to call retweeted_by_user(user, options = {}). How do I create instance of object to call this method. It is instance method, correct?

I did this for Twitter::REST::CLIENT

```
 client = client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key     = "..."
  config.consumer_secret  = "..."
  config.access_token     = "..."
  config.access_token_secret = "..."
end
```

but it does not work for Twitter::Tweet

```
 client = client = Twitter::Tweet.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key     = "..."
  config.consumer_secret  = "..."
  config.access_token     = "..."
  config.access_token_secret = "..."
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) What does the code you posted have to do with calling retweeted_by_user()?

2) `I want to call retweeted_by_user(user, options = {}). How do I create instance of object to call this method. It is instance method, correct?`

If you go to the twitter gem website:

https://github.com/sferik/twitter

...then click on the Documentation link, it takes you here:

http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter

...then if you click on `Method List` in the upper right corner, and look down the list for retweeted_by_user(), and click on that link, it takes you to the method definition here:

http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Timelines#retweeted_by_user-instance_method

...then if you scroll to the top of that page, you can see that the method is defined in a *module* called:

`Twitter::REST::Timelines`

In ruby, modules are included in a class, and then instances of that class can call the (instance)methods defined in the module.  What classes include the Twitter::REST::Timelines module? At the top of the page it says:

`Included in:API`

If you click on the API link, it takes you here:

http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/API

and at the top of that page it says `Module: Twitter::REST::API`.

Okay, a module can also include another module, which means it's as if the including module itself defines the methods in the included module.  But we still need to find a class somewhere that includes that module, and at the top of the page under `Module: Twitter::REST::API`, it says `Included in:Client`, and if you click on the Client link, it takes you here:

http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Client

and that page says `Class: Twitter::REST::Client`...and that means that objects of the class Twitter:REST::Client can call the method retweeted_by_user(), so you can write something like this:

```
results = Twitter::REST::Client.new.retweeted_by_user(....)
```

In fact, on the page documenting Twitter::REST::Client, there is a heading called Instance Methods, and if you scroll down the list of methods the docs show all the instance methods that come from included modules, e.g.

```
Methods included from Timelines: #home_timeline, #mentions_timeline,
#retweeted_by_me, #retweeted_by_user, #retweeted_to_me, 
#retweets_of_me, #user_timeline
```

In regards to your code here:

```
client = client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key     = "..."
  config.consumer_secret  = "..."
  config.access_token     = "..."
  config.access_token_secret = "..."
end
```

the docs say this about Twitter::REST::Client.new(),

> Constructor Details
>
> This class inherits a constructor from Twitter::Client

If you click on the Twitter::Client link, it says:

```
- (Twitter::Client) initialize(options = {}) {|_self| ... }
```

What that means is: if you call Twitter::REST:Client.new() and you specify a block with one parameter, ruby will pass the new Twitter::Rest::Client instance to the block, and then you can call retweeted_by_user() on that object, e.g.:

```
Twitter::REST::Client.new do |twitter_rest_client_instance|
    results = twitter_rest_client_instance.retweeted_by_user(....)
    ...
end
```

Comment: I was confused about the significance of this `- (Array<Twitter::Tweet>)`  next to the retweeted_by_user method in the Timelines module. I thought it might mean that it was a method on the Tweet class? can u explain?

Comment: @TomokoYamaguchi, `Array<Twitter::Tweet>` is the return value of the retweeted_by_user() method.  And that looks like Java/C++ syntax to me.  In Java/C++, that syntax means that the return value is an Array and the elements of the Array are instances of the Twitter::Tweet class.